# Spot the difference between these two images

Tags: image, image-processing, jpeg, python-imaging-library, imaging

Programmatically, my code is detecting a difference between two classes of images, and always rejecting one class, while always allowing the other.

I have yet to find any difference between the images that yield the error and the ones that don't an yield error. But there has to be some difference, because the ones that yield an error do so 100% of the time, and the others work as expected 100% of the time.

In particular, I have inspected color format: RGB in both groups; size: no notable difference; datatype: uint8 in both; magnitude of pixel values: similar in both.

Below are two images that never work, followed by two images that always work:

- This image never works: https://www.colourbox.com/preview/11906131-maple-tree-and-grass-silhouette.jpg
- This image never works: http://feldmanphoto.com/wp-content/uploads/awe-inspiring-house-clipart-black-and-white-disney-coloring-pages-big-clipartxtras-illistration-background-housewives-bouncy.jpeg
- This image always works: http://www.spacedesign.us/wp-content/uploads/landscape-with-old-tree-and-grass-over-white-background-black-and-black-and-white-trees.jpg
- This image always works: http://www.modernhouse.co/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/1024px-RoseSeidlerHouseSulmanPrize.jpg

How can I spot the difference?

The scenario is that I am using Firebase with Swift iOS front end to send these images to a Google Cloud ML-engine hosted convnet. Some images work all the time and certain others never work as above. Further, all images work when I use the gcloud versions predict CLI. To me the issue is necessarily something in the images. Hence I am posting here for the imaging group. Code is included as requested for completeness.

CODE of index.js file is included:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const google = require('googleapis');
const sizeOf = require('image-size');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore();
const rtdb = admin.database();
const dbRef = rtdb.ref();

function cmlePredict(b64img) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        google.auth.getApplicationDefault(function (err, authClient) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            if (authClient.createScopedRequired && authClient.createScopedRequired()) {
                authClient = authClient.createScoped([
                    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
                ]);
            }

        var ml = google.ml({
           version: 'v1'
        });

        const params = {
            auth: authClient,
            name: 'projects/myproject-18865/models/my_model',
            resource: {
                instances: [
                {
                    "image_bytes": {
                    "b64": b64img
                    }
                }
                ]
            }
        };

        ml.projects.predict(params, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
}

function resizeImg(filepath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        exec(`convert ${filepath} -resize 224x ${filepath}`, (err) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error('Failed to resize image', err);
            reject(err);
          } else {
            console.log('resized image successfully');
            resolve(filepath);
          }
        });
      });
}

exports.runPrediction = functions.storage.object().onChange((event) => {

    fs.rmdir('./tmp/', (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error deleting tmp/ dir');
        }
    });

const object = event.data;
const fileBucket = object.bucket;
const filePath = object.name;
const bucket = gcs().bucket(fileBucket);
const fileName = path.basename(filePath);
const file = bucket.file(filePath);

if (filePath.startsWith('images/')) {  
    const destination = '/tmp/' + fileName;
    console.log('got a new image', filePath);
    return file.download({
        destination: destination
    }).then(() => {
        if(sizeOf(destination).width > 224) {
            console.log('scaling image down...');
            return resizeImg(destination);
        } else {
            return destination;
        }
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('base64 encoding image...');
        let bitmap = fs.readFileSync(destination);
        return new Buffer(bitmap).toString('base64');
    }).then((b64string) => {
        console.log('sending image to CMLE...');
        return cmlePredict(b64string);
    }).then((result) => {
        console.log(`results just returned and is: ${result}`);  



        let predict_proba = result.predictions[0]

        const res_pred_val = Object.keys(predict_proba).map(k => predict_proba[k])
        const res_val = Object.keys(result).map(k => result[k])

        const class_proba = [1-res_pred_val,res_pred_val]
        const opera_proba_init = 1-res_pred_val
        const capitol_proba_init = res_pred_val-0

        // convert fraction double to percentage int
        let opera_proba = (Math.floor((opera_proba_init.toFixed(2))*100))|0
        let capitol_proba = (Math.floor((capitol_proba_init.toFixed(2))*100))|0
        let feature_list = ["houses", "trees"]


        let outlinedImgPath = '';
        let imageRef = db.collection('predicted_images').doc(filePath.slice(7));
               outlinedImgPath = `outlined_img/${filePath.slice(7)}`;
               imageRef.set({
                image_path: outlinedImgPath,
                opera_proba: opera_proba,
                capitol_proba: capitol_proba
            });

        let predRef = dbRef.child("prediction_categories");
        let arrayRef = dbRef.child("prediction_array");

    predRef.set({
            opera_proba: opera_proba,
            capitol_proba: capitol_proba,
            });

       arrayRef.set({first: {
           array_proba: [opera_proba,capitol_proba],
           brief_description: ["a","b"],
           more_details: ["aaaa","bbbb"],
           feature_list: feature_list},
        zummy1: "",
        zummy2: ""});

        return bucket.upload(destination, {destination: outlinedImgPath});

    });
} else {
    return 'not a new image';
}
});
```

Comment: Clearly I assigned you more IQ points than you are willing to accept, Chris -- j/k. More seriously, I have narrowed down the search for a solution to the above described, and I need help from here. Other than the properties I already ruled out, any clues for what other image properties may be algorithmically classifying these images? Thanks!!!

Comment: Ok I will edit right now to include the code. The scenario is that I am using firebase with swift iOS front end to send these images to a google cloud ML-engine hosted convnet. Some images work all the time and certain others never work as above. Further, all images work when I use the gcloud versions predict CLI. To me the issue is necessarily something in the images. And I posted here to you imaging experts who are much smarter and experienced than I am with image properties.

Comment: Any specific error messages you get back?

Comment: It resizes input to the expected size. I will try to change one of the 'rejected' images size to the size of one of the 'accepted' images and will see what happens.

Comment: Yes this is the error: msg >TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at file.download.then.then.then.then (/user_code/index.js:128:51) at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)

Comment: Line 128 is `outlinedImgPath = 'outlined_img/${filePath.slice(7)}';`, is that right? Or did some lines shift with all the copy-pasting?

Comment: @CrisLuengo, the other reason why I would be surprised if the convnet is the problem is b/c as I stated the online-predict CLI works well for all images. I will nonetheless resize to exact same and try. Thx, will let u know how it goes shortly

Comment: @CrisLuengo, Line 128 is as presented.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, Resized to same. Problem persists.

Comment: I don't understand enough Javascript to know what that line does that generates the error. You should consider adding the Javascript tag to your question, the folks following that tag might be able to help you with this.

Comment: oh Chris, I misunderstood ur question about line 128. Yes it got shifted in copy paste. The actual line 128 is: let predict_proba = result.predictions[0]  where I attempt to access the [0] element of the CNN output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was that the bad images were grayscale, not RGB as expected by my model. I initially had checked this first by looking at the shape. But the 'bad' images had 3 color channels, each of those 3 channels stored the same number --- so my model was refusing to accept them. Also, as expected and contrary to what I initially thought I observed, turns out the gcloud ML-engine predict CLI actually also failed for these images. Took me 2 days to figure this out!